# Nem sempre usar o botao anexo

Tags: c#

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]tenho uma duvida 
o meu programa consiste em enviar e-mail com anexos mas as vezes quando não quero enviar um email com anexos da-me um erro [image: O que faço para não ter que inserir sempre anexos]

Alguém pode ajudar?

Eu consigo enviar e-mail com anexos sem problemas mas sem anexos não funciona

codigo:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Anexostxt.Text));
        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(anexos2.Text));
    }

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

    if(dlg.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK){
        string picpath = dlg.FileName.ToString();
        Anexostxt.Text = picpath;
    }
}
```

Erro  Additional information: O parâmetro 'fileName' não pode ser uma cadeia vazia.

Comment: Pela imagem está obvio que `Anexostxt.Text` está vazio, o porquê? Só o vendo o código. Mostre o trecho de código onde `Anexostxt.Text` é setado.

Comment: este print ajuda?

Comment: Não, pelo que entendi, `Anexostxt.Text` refere-se ao arquivo anexo. Portando onde está setando este método? Algo assim: `Anexostxt.Text = "c:\meuanexo.txt"`

Comment: Prefira colocar codigo e nao imagens. Coloque a mensagem da excepçao e o *stack trace* da mesma.

Comment: a mensagem é : "O parâmetro 'fileName' não pode ser uma cadeia vazia.\r\nNome do parâmetro: fileName"}

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que o `button4` seja o que envia o email, se você não quer anexos precisa verificar se o seu campo de anexo está em branco. Por exemplo:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(Anexostxt.Text != "") {
        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Anexostxt.Text));
    }
    if(anexos2.Text != "") {
        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(anexos2.Text));
    }
}
```

Isso é só um princípio básico, provavelmente você irá precisar de validações adicionais (por exemplo, verificar se os campos não contêm somente espaços, ou se apontam para um arquivo válido, etc.)

Comment: nao identifica o msg :/

Comment: Funciona!! obrigado!